# How does critical strike chance stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering how critical strike chance stacks? Say I buy a Phanton Dancer with its 30% crit chance. Now if I buy another Phanton Dancer, what is my critical chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

they stack additively, so just add up the crit chance.  1 PD will increase your total crit chance by +30%.  The 2nd PD will increase your total crit chance by +30%, so +60% crit chance total from 2 PD's.

Answer (score 3):

Crit chance caps out at 100% where your basic attacks are just crits. These are other things that stack additively

Ability power
    Armor,
    Armor penetration,
    Armor reduction,
    Attack damage,
    Attack speed ,
    Cooldown reduction,
    Critical strike chance, 
    Critical strike damage,
    Health,
    Health regeneration,
    Life steal,
    Magic penetration,
    Magic resistance,
    Magic resistance reduction,
    Mana,
    Mana regeneration, and
    Spell vamp

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Stacking